# Can I send Clipboard in as Command Parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, clipboard

Using MVVM I have a ViewModel that implements commands. I would like to receive the Clipboard contents as a parameter and do things with it.

XAML:

```
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=ClipBoardAction}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding SomeAwesomeCodeHereToPassCurrentClipboard}" />
```

c#:

```
private void ClipBoardAction(object parameter) {
    //parameter is clipboard OR CLIPBOARD DATA like string[]
 }
```

Is this possible? If so, what do I bind to in the XAML?

**EDIT**: Work around so far is to just wire the button to a Click event and put in some code behind glue.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        //manually send command to object
        string[] clipboard = Clipboard.GetText().Split(new Char[] { '\n' });
        var but = sender as Button;
        var viewModel = (FooViewModel)but.DataContext;
        if (viewModel.ClipBoardAction.CanExecute(null)){
            viewModel.ClipBoardAction.Execute(clipboard);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Clipboard` is a static class in the `System.Windows` namespace (PresentationCore). If you include this reference, you can just use `Clipboard.WhateverFunction` in the command, no need to pass parameters to it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Could you be more specific? I can't find clipboard in System, maybe I'm creating the resource incorrectly.

Comment: `System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText()` you don't have to pass it via parameter, you can just invoke this inside your `ClipboardAction`

Comment: @markokstate you reference it in the code-behind, in the ClipboardAction command in your case. See the link I provided.

Comment: I guess my goal was to handle it with the ViewModel and to avoid the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Since [Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) class provides clipboard data as methods not properties, and binding can be done with properties only, no you can't do that.

**Edit**

You may hack the problem by implementing a custom [converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) but I don't think it is much worthy:

```
public class ClipboardConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return Clipboard.GetData(value as string);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```